# How to add a field while in edit mode? SugarCRM CE

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using Sugar CRM CE. While in edit view of Opportunities, there is a + button and a - button to add or take away email fields. This allows you to click on the + and add an additional email field while in edit view. How can I add this type of feature to other custom fields? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You search for a way to add n related entries in another module.

There is no out of the box solution to my knowledge.

But I did something similar to integrate multiple fields from another module into a editview to make i.e. a product order faster.

In your case first add a javascript to the {MODULE}/metadata/editviewdefs.php:

```
$viewdefs[{MODULE}] = array (
  'EditView' => array (
    'includes' => array (
        array (
          'file' => 'modules/{MODULE}/js/selectScript.js'
     )
```

Into this file modules/{MODULE}/js/selectScript.js you put some javascript to generate the buttons (i.e. by positioning them via jquery after the description field). The script should add all the relevant information into a hidden textfield (i.e. named websites_json) which contains for example JSON like this:

```
{'websites' : ['www.somethin.it', 'www.somethingelse.com']}
```

If you have to process this information to create multiple objects in another module you could add a file in (custom/) modules/{MODULE}/Save.php in which you handle the data the javascript created, by creating the related entries. You would access the json for example by $_REQUEST['websites_json']. Then you could do with it what ever needs to be done.

In your case with only websites to add you could simply add a textfield in the main modules vardefs to hold a list of websites. So add this to the vardefs of your module to create the db field:

```
$dictionary['{MODULE}'] = array(
    'table' => '{module}',
    'fields' => array(
        'websites_json' => array (
            'name' => 'websites_json',
            'vname' => 'LBL_WEBSITES_JSON',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
```

The field gets saved automatically. On reentering editview you should recreate the websites list to edit it and in detailview you need to handle the json to display the websites as a list.

Comment: Can I automate this with an incremented value? That way there wouldn't be a finite number of fields coded in?

Comment: You aren't limited this way, the text fields json can hold as many items as the user added

Comment: Okay that sounds good. I am unsure how to construct the js file that creates fields in Sugar. To be clear I don't know how to do this. Is there a reference you could direct me to? I am very new to developing in Sugar. I am just trying to store web addresses in the text field (http://www.someaddress.com/) and allow the user to add as many as needed.

Comment: would something like this work? <script language = "javascript" >
         var JSONObj = { "website" : "somewebaddress.com" };  
      </script>

Comment: Okay I did a little research on JSON  and I learned something. :)  I found the format to be like you described as  {"WebSite":[
    {"Address":"http://www.somewebsite.com/"},
   {"Name":"Value"}
]} But I still do not understand how to have it make a new Sugar text field. Additionally Do I just assign the value of the text filed to the $_REQUEST['address'] or is it $_REQUEST['Website']?

Comment: there are a lot of ways to do this. I used a Textfield with JSON because I found it convienient but you could also just add data to the form as js array. Take a look at the include/SugarEmailAddress/SugarEmailAddress.js code that does this for email adresses. maybe you want to adapt the sugar script to your needs.

Comment: I see its just a text field. What would you say is the best way to save the data to the database? The database only has one field for this currently.  Would it be best to create database fields for each as they are added or would it be better to just make an array and set up a delimited string for storage in the existing field?  I am open to any other suggestions that you may have.

Comment: I store into a separate module. So n entries of orders in my case. You could choose json to store as many objects as you want into a textfield / varchar in db. searching could be troublesome in some occasions but with websites in there it should work.

Comment: What is the best way to store the json data into a Database? I understand you use $_REQUEST['ObjectName'] to get the data but how would be best to insert that into the Database?

Comment: Make it the standard sugar way. Meaning you add the field to vardefs make repair and rebuild to create it in the db. After that add it as hidden textfield let it get the json as contents and that's it in your case. It gets stored like all the other fields.

Comment: Forgive me another follow up question. If it stores the JSON as varchar I would need to handle that on the detail view am I right? So I would put a script in view.detail.php that catch the data then parse the JSONdata into the correct number of text fields. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: You do. But a script included  in detailviewdefs.php would suffice too and this would be update safe

Comment: I am having some trouble creating a table and assigning the values to the JSON array. I have been going through google and trying many things and I am confused. I can get sugar to make a new field with the javascript but this is as far as I can get. Please help.

Comment: I see you edited the code above however I am unsure how I am supposed to make a hidden field that has Json.  Do you put `<input type="hidden" name="website_json" id="Site" value=" Is this where I place the JSON- If so I am unsure how it should be structured? "/>` How do I ensure the script grabs each field and not just the 1st field over and over.

Comment: Each time a website is added it should be added to the json. In your case because you only have websites you could also comma separate them in the field without json. Maybe that is easier for you. Adding the field as hidden is done by using the editviewdefs and there a custom_code field. Or add it from your js initially. Sorry bro the rest is up to you unless you want to hire me :-)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if add a script in the .js file that just grabs the value of the field and pushes it into a JSON object then stringify and pass the string into the field and let sugar save the string. Then I can just handle the string on each of the views to populate the fields on display. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Yes sounds right but like I wrote in your case you could simply add the websites comma separated without the json if you want to do it easier