# Add more button like email field for another field in SugarCRM?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I want to create a custom field which should have 'Add more button or + Sign just like email field ' so that we can add as many as we want..(like email address field with + symbol to add more you can see in Contact Module).Is it possible in SugarCRM studio ? 
i searched on Google but noting found yet.

Comment: Appart from the MultiSelect with the predefined values, I think it would require custom php code

Comment: This topic was discussed in a [previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098301/how-to-add-a-field-while-in-edit-mode-sugarcrm-ce).